# How to get enum values without knowing its keys?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-translate

I'm trying to load a combo with an enumerator from Translation API. But, I don't know how to iterate and get both the key and value of each item and show it to the user. Can anyone tell me how to do this???

The object I'm trying to access is *google.language.Languages*. It is built this way:

```
google.language.Languages{
'AFRIKAANS' : 'af',  
'ALBANIAN' : 'sq',  
'AMHARIC' : 'am',  
'ARABIC' : 'ar',  
'ARMENIAN' : 'hy', 
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(language in google.language.Languages)
{
    alert(google.language.Languages[language]);
}
```

?